# Java function calling and return value in Android

Tags: java, android, function

I have a Java class with some code to be operated based on flag value, below is my code which works as flag value is 1

```
if(flag==1)
{
    Log.d("Flag value", "flag= "+flag);
    System.out.println("Read have "+read());
    String tt=read();
    s1=tt;
}
```

From this above function the value in the variable "s1" is some string value returned by read() function.

the output of this code is returning two times of read() function, like

s1 having "StringString"

Here is my read function code

```
public String read(){

          try{
             FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);
             int c;

             while( (c = fin.read()) != -1)
             {
                temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
             }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {

          }
          Log.d("INSIDE READ FUNC", "temp have "+temp);
        return temp;
       }
```

While I omitted this "System.out.println("Read have "+read());" by below code

```
if(flag==1)
    {
        Log.d("Flag value", "flag= "+flag);
        //System.out.println("Read have "+read());
        String tt=read();
        s1=tt;
    }
```

And I got the perfect output like

s1 having "String"

How come the code works like this? I called the read() function only once to store to "tt" variable.

And storing the tt variable to s1 variable.

But when I use System.out.println("Read have "+read()); its invoking and storing the returned string value in array and in the second time I am storing to the "tt" String variable and its appending the last returned string from the read() function to the "tt" String variable.

So the "tt" String variable having two times of read() function Returned String.
How it is storing two times?

Comment: Can you post the code to the read() method? I think that is probably where the value is getting saved and appended again.

Comment: i updated with read funtion now, check it @DavidCAdams

Comment: because when you call read() it jumps current pointer to next character.

Comment: but i stored only once to a variable right? @BirajZalavadia

Comment: just add `temp = ""` above try catch part in read() method..

Comment: i already did before onCreate method @BlackTiger

Comment: but when you call read() method you need to clear temp String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(flag==1)
    {
        Log.d("Flag value", "flag= "+flag);
        //System.out.println("Read have "+read());
        String tt=read();
        s1=tt;
    }
```

in above code `read()` method is calls twice. And inside `read()` method variable **"temp"** is declared global and you are concat the data like

```
temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
```

so value is concat twice in temp variable.

**To Resolve the issue declare temp as local variable like**

```
public String read(){
          String temp="";
          try{
             FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);
             int c;

             while( (c = fin.read()) != -1)
             {
                temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
             }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {

          }
          Log.d("INSIDE READ FUNC", "temp have "+temp);
        return temp;
       }
```

Comment: Define String temp above the try catch statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
```

You don't define temp in the read() method, so it is probably defined as a global variable. This means that every time you call the read() method, you are appending the new values to it. 
You should probably define temp in your read() method:

```
String temp;
```

that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = Context.openFileInput(someFileName);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while ((int bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
   bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```